# Get January Date Month Record

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlite

i need help on my query . i was trying to generate a list from January to Febuary. however on my query im not sure which part that i did wrong or mistake its only grab Febuary record. Kindly advise . Thanks you

```
    set @FirstDateOfNextMth = CONVERT(varchar,dateadd(d,-(day(dateadd(m,1,getdate()-2))),dateadd(m,1,getdate())),112)
set @LastDateOfNextMth = CONVERT(varchar,dateadd(d,-(day(dateadd(m,2,getdate()))),DATEADD(m,2,getdate())),112)


--------------------------------------------------

INSERT INTO [dbo].[ProcessLog] ([LogTime] ,[LogDescription] ,[LogRemark])
VALUES (GETDATE(), 'Import Client Info', '')

--------------------------------------------------

SET @sSQL = 'SELECT DISTINCT CHDR.CHDRNUM, ZTRN.CCDATE, CHDR.CRDATE, CLNT.CLNTNUM, CLNT.SURNAME, CLNT.GIVNAME,
            CLNT.SECUITYNO, ZCLN.EMAIL from (((MPIDTA.ZTRNPF AS ZTRN 
            LEFT JOIN MPIDTA.CHDRPF AS CHDR ON ZTRN.RLDGACCT = CHDR.CHDRNUM AND ZTRN.EFFDATE = CHDR.CURRFROM)
            LEFT JOIN MPIDTA.CLNTPF AS CLNT ON CHDR.COWNNUM = CLNT.CLNTNUM)
            LEFT JOIN MPIDTA.ZCLNPF AS ZCLN ON CLNT.CLNTNUM = ZCLN.CLNTNUM)
            where (ZTRN.BATCPFX = ''BA'' AND ZTRN.BATCCOY = ''1''
            AND ZTRN.CNTTYPE = ''PTB'' AND ZTRN.TRANDATE >= ''20140101'' 
            AND (ZTRN.EXPIRY_DATE BETWEEN ' + @FirstDateOfNextMth + ' AND ' + @LastDateOfNextMth + '))
            AND (CHDR.MPLNUM = '''' AND CHDR.CHDRPFX = ''CH''
            AND CHDR.CHDRCOY = ''1'' AND CHDR.VALIDFLAG = ''1'')'

SET @sExe = 'Insert into dbo.TPA_Client_Info Select * FROM OPENQUERY(AS400, ''' + REPLACE(@sSQL, '''', '''''') + ''')'

exec (@sExe)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in `@FirstDateOfNextMth`.

```
set @FirstDateOfNextMth = CONVERT(varchar,dateadd(d,-(day(dateadd(m,1,getdate()-2))),
                          dateadd(m,1,getdate())),112)
```

Result is `20150202`

since the `@FirstDateOfNextMth` is `20150202` in where condition `ZTRN.EXPIRY_DATE` is filtered between `feb` month alone. Try changing like this.

```
 set @FirstDateOfNextMth = DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate()), 0)
```